# Limit chars per line in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a non-resizeable textarea. I need it to work as follows:

When the user enters text, and they hit 76 characters, they should not be able to type anymore until they hit enter

OR

It should continue to the next line as a new line.

I tried to process it post-submission, to add newlines every 76 chars, but it added too many spaces, and when I trimmed, got rid of required spaces.

What's the fastest, most user friendly way to do this?

```
<textarea class="edit_note_text"></textarea>
```

```js
var text = $('.edit_note_text').val();
```

```css
.edit_note_text{
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    border-color: #dcdcdc;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    margin: 10px 16px 0px;
    width: 780px;
    height: 160px;
        position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    flex-direction: column;
    outline: none;
        cursor: text;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="edit_note_text" cols='76'></textarea>
```

I have tried several ways of fixing this with CSS, but I don't think CSS is the answer. I thought of using Javascript on keyup, but there are ways around that.

Comment: where's your code? what error you got?

Answer (score 0):

Use `keydown` combined with `preventDefault`. When the user presses a key inside of your textarea, get the `value` property of the textarea. Use `.split("\n")` to split it into individual lines, and run `event.preventDefault()` if any have a length greater than 76:

```js
function keyDown(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    var lines = text.value.split("\n");
    var line = text.value.substring(0, text.selectionStart).split("\n").length - 1;
    if (lines[line].length >= 76 && !(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 8))
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" onkeydown="keyDown(event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please note that you can copy/paste text into the textbox and it will be longer. Trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<textarea id="myarea" cols="76" wrap="hard"></textarea>
```

this will only allow 76 chars per line

Comment: This continues text on the next line, but when it saves, is actually longer than 76 char per line - because it isn't a real newline.